# How to make a class stored data to a variable an callback with method?

Tags: php, class, oop

I am interested in how this works:

```
<?php
$Query = $mysqli->query("select * from table");
$Query->fetch_array(); // <== How to make $Query a class/method like this?
?>
```

How do you assign a method to a variable and then have that variable be able to call another method like the `$mysqli` and `$Query` example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are *(I think)* referring to, is by returning an object. It goes against the principle of dependency injection, but it's one way to do it.

```
class MyClassA
    {
        public function myFunction()
            {
                return new MyClassB();
            }
    }

class MyClassB
    {
        public function execute()
            {
                return true;
            }
    }

// Start use
$class  = new MyClassA();
// Assign variable to function which returns object
$newObj = $class->myFunction();
// Will write "1" because now $newObj is MyClassB()
echo $newObj->execute();
```

Another way is to return `$this` from the first method. The usage of the above object would work identical in this instance, however you also allow another principle known as method chaining:

```
class MyClassA
    {
        public function myFunction()
            {
                return $this;
            }

        public function execute()
            {
                return true;
            }
    }

// Same as above works
$class  = new MyClassA();
$sameObj = $class->myFunction();
echo $sameObj->execute();

// Allowing for Method Chain
$class  = new MyClassA();
// Allowing for chaining
echo $class->myFunction()->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate your class and call it's function with ->

```
$class = new MyClass(); // Instantiate class

$class->myFunction(); // Use it's function
```

PHP manual example of creating a class:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php